# IMDB API Search Movie by Category or Rating

Tags: api, movie, imdb

Is there any API given by any third party that would return movies by that category or rating.
For example below is the link for getting movies by

1) IMDB ID
2) Title and Year 
http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/

There is another 3rd party which gives Movie and its details against any title given.
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=abc

I want a list of movies by category or rating. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sf.net/): it can take the plain text data files distributed by IMDb and put them into a SQL database.
From here, you can easily create a custom query to retrieve the data you need.